# Why isn't $\int_0^R 2\pi r \,dr$ equal to $\int_0^D \pi d \,dd$, assuming $D=2R$?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

The argument that I have seen for the area of the circle begins with the definition of the circumference, $C=2\pi r$. Then, the argument is that the area of the circle can be found by adding the circumferences of an infinite number of circles from radius $0$ to $R$ (some constant radius). That is,

$\int_0^R 2\pi r \,dr = \pi R^2$

My thought is why can't this argument apply to the diameter as well? Assuming that $d=2r$, where $d$ is the diameter, and the definition of the circumference is $C=\pi d$, then the area of the circle should be able to be found by adding the circumferences of an infinite number of circles from diameter $0$ to $D$ (some constant diameter).

$\int_0^D \pi d \,dd = \frac{\pi D^2}{2}$

Assuming that $D=2R$, why aren't these two integrals equal to each other?

Comment: You don't have a better variable to use other than $d$?  No offense, but$\int \pi d\ dd$ is ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the substitution $d=2r$, we have $dd=2dr$. Hence,
$$
\int_0^R 2\pi r \, dr=\int_0^{2R} d\pi \left(\frac{dd}{2} \right)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2R}d\pi \, dd.
$$

As an aside, I think your misconception isn't in the picture, geometrically, but rather in the fact that the rate that you apply the base in the infinitesimal is important.

Answer (score 1):

You have to adjust for the factor of $2$ in the differential. We have
$$dd = 2dr$$
so
$$dr=\frac 12 dd$$
Thus the integral is
$$\int \frac{\pi d}2 dd$$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of integrating from $0$ to $D = 2R$, assume that you integrate from $-R$ to $R$, then the integral of 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^D \pi x \textrm{d}x = \int_{-R}^{R} \pi x \textrm{d} x
\end{equation}
sums all the circles with diameter $x$ twice. Since you count each circle once when it crosses the diameter left of the midpoint of the circle, and once when it crosses the diameter right of the midpoint of the circle.

So you have to take a factor $1/2$ to account for the double counting.